# How to convert any Java or Scala object to a JSON object, and is it possible to bypass any serialization/deserialization with this?

Tags: java, json, scala, user-defined-functions, json-deserialization

I am working with some big data processing. For every row of a large dataframe table we have data stored as objects, and we have a function that expects a JSON object and runs some evaluations on that object. Currently we are serializing our object into a string and then deserializing it into a json object for processing.

At scale, serialization and deserialization are very costly, so I am wondering if there is a way to convert a java/scala object directly to a json object, and if I am even correct in assuming that this would bypass any deserialization and improve performance.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) It is not possible to convert *any* Java or Scala object to JSON.  For example, a `Thread` or `Process` object will not be representable as JSON.  2) It is not possible to bypass serialization.  Conversion to JSON is serialization.  And you can't convert to JSON without converting to JSON.

Comment: 3) The cost of serializing using `ObjectOutputStream` will be comparable to serializing to JSON using a POJO <-> JSON mapping ... such as Jackson.

Comment: Having said that, when you say *"currently we are serializing our object into a string and then deserializing it into a json object for processing"* it is not clear what you are actually saying.  Do you actually mean that you are deserializing to a `JSONObject` instance ... for some specific `JSONObject` class?  ("JSON object" typically means the serialized form.) Perhaps it would help if you showed us some relevant code.